# MFC displaying png with transparent background

Tags: c++, mfc, png

I need a way to display a PNG image with transparent background on a background with gradient color.

I have tried this:

```
CImage img;
CBitmap bmp;
img.Load(_T(".\\res\\foo.png"));
bmp.Attach(img.Detach());
CDC dcStatus;
dcStatus.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
dcStatus.SelectObject(&bmp);
dcStatus.SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT);
dc.BitBlt(rectText.left + 250, rectText.top, 14, 14, &dcStatus, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
bmp.DeleteObject();
```

but foo.png gets black background wherever it is transparent in original image.

I did try to do a new bitmap that was painted with transparent color and did all possible operations on it, but that didn't help. Sample of one permutation:

```
CImage img;
CBitmap bmp;
img.Load(_T(".\\res\\foo.png"));
bmp.Attach(img.Detach());
CBitmap bmpMaska;
bmpMaska.CreateBitmap(14, 14, 1, 1, NULL);
CDC dcStatus;
dcStatus.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
dcStatus.SelectObject(&bmp);
CDC dcMaska;
dcMaska.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
dcMaska.SelectObject(&bmpMaska);
dcMaska.SetBkColor(dcStatus.GetPixel(0, 0));
//TODO: Bitmap ni transparent
dc.BitBlt(rectText.left + 250, rectText.top, 14, 14, &dcMaska, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
dc.BitBlt(rectText.left + 250, rectText.top, 14, 14, &dcStatus, 0, 0, SRCAND);  
bmp.DeleteObject();
bmpMaska.DeleteObject();
```

This did not do the trick. Either, there was all black square on the screen, or the result was the same as original.

I have also checked AlphaBlend API, but my code must be pure MFC + C++ witthout any additional APIs. 
**[Edit]:** Company policy is as little APIs as possible. The code is supposed to run on embedded windows systems in real time.

**[Edit 2]:** I am not bound to PNG image format, meaning, anything that will display as transparent, goes.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The old bitmap calls that MFC exposes can't handle alpha. AlphaBlend is the way to go, it's part of the same Windows API that's used internally by MFC. What's the reason for not using it?

Comment: Stupid company policy of using as little APIs as possible. Specially, since application runs on embedded windows systems.

Comment: Good luck to you then.

Comment: Oi @MarkRansom... Assuming I use AlphaBlend... what would I need to do to achieve desired result. As far as I can see from samples AlphaBlend is used to set opacity.

Comment: I forgot to ask, is the .png file 8 or 24 bits?

Comment: I didn't do any reduction, so basically it is either 24 or 32 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Convert the png to a 32 bit bmp file. Google 'AlphaConv' and use that. PNG's are a PITA to work with - several API's claim to support them but actually don't, or only partially, or only on some platforms etc.
- Load your 32-bit bmp using CBitmap::LoadBitmap (from resources - this is by far the easiest)
- Then use CDC::AlphaBlend() to draw your bitmap. TransparentBlt() doesn't work with an alpha channel - it's just either draw the pixel or not. AlphaBlend is part of the win32 API, and you could still investigate CImage::AlphaBlend if you'd like, but that has a bug somewhere (I forgot what exactly) so I always use the raw ::AlphaBlend.
- But beware - you need to premultipy the alpha channel for correct display. See my answer on [How to draw 32-bit alpha channel bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307348/how-to-draw-32-bit-alpha-channel-bitmaps) .

No variation of what you described will work. You need another API to get this to work. Or, you could use GetDIBits and do your own version of ::AlphaBlend() :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're asking for (simply some set of pixels being transparent) it's probably easiest to use a 24- or 32-bit BMP, and simply pick a color to treat as transparent. Pre-process your picture to take any pixel that precisely matches your transparent color and increase change the least significant bit of one of the channels.

Given 8 bits per channel, this won't normally cause a visible change. Then draw the pixels you want transparent in one exact color. This is easy to do in something like a paint program.

You can then draw that to your DC using [`TransparentBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141.aspx). That lets you specify the color you want to treat as transparent.

Comment: Would that work with anti-aliasing as well? Basically, my image is a painted circle on transparent background. If I change transparent to let's say pink, some pixels will not be pink, but will not have the color of either app background or circle itself.